# Video.js integration with Vue3

Tags: html, vuejs3, video.js

I've a simple html page which displays an RTMP stream from nginx server and it works without any issue. Here is the working html code:

```html
<div id="middlebox">
    <h2>RTMP Stream</h2>
    <video
        id="uav1-video"
        class="video-js"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        width="640"
        height="480"
        data-setup="{}">
        <source src="/hls/stream1.m3u8" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" />
    </video>
  </div>
```

Now I want to integrate this functionality into Vue3 application. I added the following in `<template>` and `<script>` tag of a view component:

```html
<template>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div>
     <h2>RTMP Stream</h2>
     <video
        id="my-video"
        class="video-js"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        width="320"
        height="180"
        data-setup="{}">
        <source src="/hls/stream1.m3u8" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" />
      </video>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
    name : 'View',

    data() {
        return{
        }
    },
    mounted() {
       let videoScript = document.createElement('script')
       videoScript.setAttribute('src', './js/video.js')
       document.head.appendChild(videoScript)
    },
  }
</script>
```

With the above code only video player appears on the html page but I'm unable to play the stream. I don't see the big play button which I see in the html page.

[image: video-player]

When I check the html page in the browser, I see the following exception:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'   js/video.js:1
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: What does js/video.js look like? It seems that somethings gone wrong there?

Comment: The issue was with the path of video.js. I'm hosting my web page using express.js. After I copied the video.js into `public/js` folder, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Videojs has a pretty specific way of being setup. I haven’t been able to adapt it to fully customize in Vue3 yet. But, if you look at the videojs website and navigate to the Vue instructions follow them exactly as it says and setup a component then load that component into your page it will work.

Comment: Hi tec21, thanks for taking time to answer the question. 
I have one advice on the answer, While your answer might be generally helpful but it might not be a solution to the specific question asked. The question had a clear error that was happening. I think we could point the person who asked back to this error and ask him to ether follow the error on that specific code or ask that they provide the content of the file mentioned in the error. 

Again, thanks for taking your time to help others solve their issues and help this community grow. 

Best regards